# Gauss's Law in action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

Need someone to tell me if I got this done correctly

(a) Draw Gaussuian cylinder inside the black cylinder to find charge enclosed

$Q_{en} = Q(\frac{r}{a})^2$

Apply Gauss's Law

$E2\pi r \ell = \dfrac{Q\left ( \frac{r}{a} \right )^2}{\varepsilon_0}$

$E = \dfrac{Q\left ( \frac{r}{a} \right )^2}{2 \pi r \ell\varepsilon_0} = \dfrac{Qr}{2\pi \varepsilon_0  a^2\ell}$

$E = \dfrac{\rho r}{2 \varepsilon_0}$

(b) Basically same principle, but the total charge of the black cylinder

$E = \dfrac{\rho a^2}{2r \varepsilon_0}$

(c) 0 under static equilibrium

(d) The enclosed charge should be a sum of cylinders' charges.

$Q_{en} = \rho V + \lambda \ell = \rho \pi a^2 \ell + \lambda \ell = \ell ( \rho \pi a^2 + \lambda)$

Hence

$E2\pi r \ell = \dfrac{\ell ( \rho \pi a^2 + \lambda)}{\varepsilon_0} \implies E =\dfrac{ \rho \pi a^2 + \lambda}{2 \pi r \varepsilon_0} $

The term looks very awkward, so it's probably wrong.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for a), note that $Q=\rho \pi a^2 l$.

Comment: Wow I feel really stupid all of sudden.

Comment: Wait, if I sub in $Q=\rho \pi a^2 l$, I get answer for (b)

Comment: Looks like that

Comment: How can that happen? Doesn't make sense to me. cylinders aren't point charges. Did I do (d) right?

Comment: I don't understand what point charges have to do with that. And no, your (d) is not right. E.g., you should write $\rho \pi a^2$ instead of $\rho \pi r^2$. As for (b), again, maybe I misunderstood you, but the enclosed charge does not depend on the radius of the point in (b). By the way, I believe $R$ in your answers is the same as $a$. Another thing, $Q$ in your answers is not the enclosed charge in (a), but just a coefficient in the expression for the enclosed charge.

Comment: Yes you are right. I chnged r and R and a many times without realizing. I corrected the typos.

Comment: (b) is still wrong.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I somehow overlooked (b). Do you know how to write these fields vectorially? I know it kinda goes out like a circle. I am thinking about $\hat{r} + 0\hat{k}$

Comment: Well, you can introduce and use unit vectors in the cylindrical coordinates, along the directions of increase of $r$,$\phi$, and $z$.